# got errors when import mod_python

Tags: python, python-module, mod-python

After finishing install mod_python, I got 500 Internal Server Error. I looked up the log, it says: 
python_handler: Can't get/create interpreter.

Then I open a python terminal and to test if I can import mod_python. Then I got errors as follows:

```
>>> import mod_python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/version.py", line 3
    version = "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I installed mod_python with command --with-python=/usr/bin/python which version is 2.7.3.

Any ideas why this happens? Thanks ahead!

EDIT: I tried to reinstall mod_python with python2.6, I found I missed the SyntaxError posted during installation.

```
SyntaxError: ('EOL while scanning string literal', ('/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/version.py', 3, 79, 'version = "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git\n'))
```

This error did appear during the installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem using mod_python-3.5.0.  The problem seems to be in the dist/version.sh file which runs git, but since the distribution doesn't have the .git repository structure, the error is generated.

I fixed version.sh by just replacing the offending line with an empty definition:

```
#GIT=`git describe --always`
GIT=
```

Answer (score 1):

or remove the line

`GIT='git describe --always'`

in /usr/local/src/mod_python-3.5.0/dist/version.sh